# How to call function of one class from another class programatically

Tags: objective-c

I  called  function of one view controller class from other view controller  in nib file using first responder before.But now I want to do it programatically.

Suppose,I have a 2 controller class named A and B.where B is root controller.I have a button(added programatically)named (Btn) in my A controller class.now I want to call  function( FuncB) of Class B when I pressed Btn of Class A.how can I do this??

I dont have any nib file in my class A.
plz someone ans my question.
Advanced thanks for ur reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I've interpreted your question correctly, but if `b` is an object instance of the `B` class, and `methodB` is a method of the `B` class, you can call `methodB` via:

```
[b methodB];
```

I am assuming by "function", you actually mean "method"...?

Answer (score 1):

Alloc and init an instance of this class and call your method. Class "functions" are called methods.

```
BController *myBController = [[BController alloc] init]; // alloc and init Controller B
[myBController MethodB]; // Call your class method
[myBController release]; // release your instance object
```

Any questions? Just comment.